# undefined reference to main issue

Tags: c, unix

I have written a c code  file called "utilfunc.c" this code contains my  functions that  I will use through my code.

Now when I am compiling my "utilfunc.c"  file an error happened  telling me that undefined reference to 'main'  error message . But on this code I don't want the `main` . What I want is just implementations for my functions.

Can anybody tell me what is happening here?

here is my code :

```
include "prodcon.h"

static void signalHandler(int signo)
{
    signalflag = 1; // Set the signal flag
}

void initializeWait(void)
{
    /* Link handler functions */
    if (signal(SIGUSR1, signalHandler) == SIG_ERR)
    {
        perror("signal");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (signal(SIGUSR2, signalHandler) == SIG_ERR)
    {
        perror("signal");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Clear masks */
    sigemptyset(&nomask);
    sigemptyset(&newmask);

    /* Add signals to mask sets */
    sigaddset(&newmask, SIGUSR1);
    sigaddset(&newmask, SIGUSR2);

    /* Block SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2, and save current signal mask. */
    if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &newmask, &oldmask) < 0)
    {
        perror("sigprocmask");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void signalParent(pid_t pid)
{
    kill(pid, SIGUSR2); // Child tells parent that it is done
}   

void waitParent(void)
{
    while (signalflag == 0)
    {
        sigsuspend(&nomask);    // Wait for signal from parent
    }

    signalflag = 0; // Clear the singalflag

    /* Restore the signal mask to old value */
    if (sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &oldmask, NULL) < 0)
    {
        perror("sigprocmask");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Add `-c` to your compiler invocation, so that you only *compile* the translation unit but do not *link* it to a complete program:

```
gcc -c -o foo.o foo.c
```

Comment: Great but can you explain this more to me?

Comment: @arzeramade: Yes: when you are compiling your "utilfunc.c" file, you need to add the command line flag `-c` to your compiler command line.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the options you give the compiler (you didn't show any, so I can't say specifically about yours), the compiler/linker will try to build a whole application, in which case it would need main defined. But you can provide different options to tell it to just compile the file given, and stop there, which sounds like what you want.

Comment: That's what I really want :)

Answer (score 1):

This was not the issue for the original poster, but here is an unusual cause for the same error message: option with missing path.

```
gcc -I../include -O -I. -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -O3 -fPIC -I -c graph.c -o graph.o
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
/home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/glibc-2.19/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/start.S:118: undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Notice the spurious `-I` before `-c graph.c`. Without it it compiles just fine

```
gcc -I../include -O -I. -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -O3 -fPIC -c graph.c -o graph.o
```

The problem is that the path is missing (`-I<path>`).
Adding the cwd as a path (`-I.`) works fine for instance

```
gcc -I../include -O -I. -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -O3 -fPIC -I. -c graph.c -o graph.o
```

Any missing path after any command can yield this error; for instance with `-L`.

```
gcc -I../include -O -I. -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -O3 -fPIC -L -c graph.c -o graph.o
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
/home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/glibc-2.19/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/start.S:118: undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: I think you overlooked what actually went wrong here... `-I -c` means to treat `-c` as an include path.

Comment: @M.M  Thanks for stating it clearly. I did suspect that, but paths are (almost ?) always stated just after the `-I`, as in the [manual of `gcc`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html), without any space in-between. But down in the  `man gcc` page, space seems to be allowed, indeed. Anyway, this can be quite surprising. Hope this answer, with your comment, can help others figure it out quickier.